# Angular 2 : How can i change the button caption from add to edit on click of the list

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms

How can I change the button caption from add to edit on click of the list
Following is my template:

```
 <div>
 <label>Task:</label> <input #taskNameRef/>
   <button (click)="addTask(taskNameRef);">Add</button>
  </div>
 <ul class="tasks">
 <li *ngFor="let task of tasks"  (click)="onSelect(task)" 
   [class.selected]="task === selectedTask">
   <span>{{task.taskName}}</span>
   <button (click)="deleteTask(task.taskName);" class="delete">x</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Following is my component code when we select the task from the list:

```
selectedTask: Task;    

onSelect(task: Task): void {
  this.selectedTask = task;
}
```

Note: I am just a beginner to the Angular2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this below is the simplest one:

```
<button *ngIf="!this.isEditBtn" (click)="addTask(taskNameRef);">Add</button>
<button *ngIf="this.isEditBtn" (click)="editTask(taskNameRef);">Edit</button>
```

In the component:

```
isEditBtn = false;
onSelectList(task){
    this.isEditBtn = !this.isEditBtn;
}
```